# undefined reference to `dlopen' 'dlsym' dlcose'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, configure, dlopen

I am using UBUNTU 12.04 and trying to install multicube explorer for Design Space Exploration.
I am new with these makefile and linux internals.
I follow these steps for installation

```
./configure
make
```

and then I get error message. Following is the log (command line reformatted for readability).

```
root@root:/home/snu/Desktop/m3explorer# make
g++ -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lxml2 -ldl \
    -Wl,--no-as-needed,-export-dynamic -pthread \
    m3_commands.o m3_env.o m3_point.o m3_sim_utils.o \
    m3_database.o m3_grammar.o m3_map.o m3_opt_utils.o \
    m3_pointer_trash.o m3_tokens.o m3_object.o m3_shell.o \
    m3_vector.o m3_driver_utils.o m3_parser.o m3_shell_variables.o \
    m3_list.o m3_object_utils.o m3_arg.o m3_common_utils.o \
    m3_exception.o m3_design_space.o m3_doe_utils.o m3_gen_html.o \
    m3_xdr_api.o m3_rsm.o -o m3explorer
m3_commands.o: In function `prs_command_db_export_xml(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x379c): undefined reference to `xmlKeepBlanksDefault'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x37a6): undefined reference to `xmlThrDefIndentTreeOutput'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x37b0): undefined reference to `xmlThrDefTreeIndentString'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x37ba): undefined reference to `xmlNewDoc'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x37d0): undefined reference to `xmlNewNode'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x37f0): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3809): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3822): undefined reference to `xmlDocSetRootElement'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3a6c): undefined reference to `xmlNewChild'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3a8b): undefined reference to `xmlNewChild'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3aaa): undefined reference to `xmlNewChild'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3aea): undefined reference to `xmlNewChild'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3b19): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3cb2): undefined reference to `xmlNewChild'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3d75): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3d98): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3e94): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3f30): undefined reference to `xmlNewChild'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3f5f): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x3fad): undefined reference to `xmlNewProp'
m3_commands.cc:(.text+0x407e): undefined reference to `xmlSaveFileEnc'
m3_opt_utils.o: In function `opt_select_optimizer(m3_env*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
m3_opt_utils.cc:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `dlopen'
m3_opt_utils.cc:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `dlsym'
m3_driver_utils.o: In function `drv_select_driver(m3_env*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
m3_driver_utils.cc:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `dlopen'
m3_driver_utils.cc:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `dlsym'
m3_driver_utils.cc:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `dlerror'
m3_common_utils.o: In function `m3_look_for_filename_in_search_path(m3_env*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
m3_common_utils.cc:(.text+0x403): undefined reference to `dlopen'
m3_common_utils.cc:(.text+0x430): undefined reference to `dlclose'
m3_doe_utils.o: In function `doe_select_doe(m3_env*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
m3_doe_utils.cc:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `dlopen'
m3_doe_utils.cc:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [m3explorer] Error 1
```

Following is the makefile contents

```
# Makefile for Multicube Explorer 
# 
# (C) Politecnico di Milano and V. Zaccaria

DSTDIR = /home/snu/Desktop/m3explorer
SRCDIR = /home/snu/Desktop/m3explorer/src
INCDIR = /home/snu/Desktop/m3explorer/src
GPLDIR = /home/snu/Desktop/m3explorer/gpl
OTHERCFLAGS = 
OTHERCXXFLAGS = -D__M3EXPLORER_VERSION__=\"release_1_1\" -I/usr/include/libxml2
OTHERLINKFLAGS = -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lxml2
GPLCXXFLAGS = 
GPLLINKFLAGS = 
IMAGE = /home/snu/Desktop/m3explorer/image
BUILDSHEPARD = no
BUILDSPLINE= no
BUILDNEURAL= nn
BUILDRBF= no
BUILDREGRESSION= no

CXX=g++
AR=ar cr
RANLIB=ranlib
SHLIB_LD=g++ -fPIC
 CFLAGS= $(OTHERCFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)         
#CFLAGS= -Wall -g -I/usr/include/libxml2         commented by Tarun. If you want to uncomment. then comment next line

 CXXFLAGS= $(OTHERCXXFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)      
#CXXFLAGS=-lxml2                                        commented by Tarun. If you want to uncomment. then comment next line

GPLCXXFLAGS += $(OTHERCXXFLAGS) 

OS_NAME = $(shell uname -s)

ifeq ("$(OS_NAME)", "SunOS")
CXXFLAGS += -D__SOLARIS__
CXXSOFLAGS = -shared -fPIC 
endif

ifeq ("$(OS_NAME)", "Darwin")
CXXFLAGS += -g -D__MAC_OSX__
CXXSOFLAGS = -fno-common -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress
endif

ifeq ("$(OS_NAME)", "Linux")
CXXFLAGS += -pthread
CXXSOFLAGS = -g -shared -fPIC 
OTHERLINKFLAGS += -ldl -Wl,--no-as-needed,-export-dynamic -pthread     #--no-as-needed, is added by tarun
endif

#####################################
#     CREATE SYMBOLIC TARGETS       #
#####################################


M3EXPLORER_TARGETS = m3_commands.o m3_env.o m3_point.o m3_sim_utils.o m3_database.o m3_grammar.o m3_map.o m3_opt_utils.o m3_pointer_trash.o m3_tokens.o m3_object.o m3_shell.o m3_vector.o m3_driver_utils.o m3_parser.o m3_shell_variables.o m3_list.o m3_object_utils.o m3_arg.o m3_common_utils.o m3_exception.o m3_design_space.o m3_doe_utils.o m3_gen_html.o m3_xdr_api.o m3_rsm.o

M3EXPLORER_INCLUDES = m3_commands.h m3_driver_utils.h m3_list.h m3_object_utils.h m3_parser.h m3_shell_variables.h m3_database.h m3_env.h m3_map.h m3_opt_utils.h m3_point.h m3_sim_utils.h m3_driver.h m3_object.h m3_optimizer.h m3_pointer_trash.h m3_vector.h m3_arg.h m3_common_utils.h m3_exception.h m3_design_space.h m3_doe.h m3_doe_utils.h drivers/libm3_xml_driver.h m3_gen_html.h m3_xdr_api.h m3_rsm.h

M3EXPLORER_INCDIR_INCLUDES = $(patsubst %.h, $(INCDIR)/%.h, $(M3EXPLORER_INCLUDES))

OPTIMIZERS_SRC = libm3_pareto_doe.cc libm3_aprs.cc libm3_mosa.cc libm3_mopso.cc libm3_nsga_II.cc libm3_linear_scan.cc libm3_femo.cc libm3_semo.cc libm3_gemo.cc
OPTIMIZERS_TARGET = $(patsubst %.cc, %.so, $(OPTIMIZERS_SRC))

DOE_SRC = libm3_full_doe.cc libm3_random_doe.cc libm3_two_level_ff.cc libm3_two_level_ff_extended.cc libm3_scrambled_doe.cc
DOE_TARGET = $(patsubst %.cc, %.so, $(DOE_SRC))

DRIVERS_SRC = libm3_test_driver.cc libm3_xml_driver.cc libm3_dtlz_driver.cc 
# libm3_counter_driver.cc
DRIVERS_TARGET = $(patsubst %.cc, %.so, $(DRIVERS_SRC))

# Tells make to search for sources into SRCDIR, SRCDIR/optimizers and SRCDIR/drivers
VPATH=$(SRCDIR):$(SRCDIR)/optimizers:$(SRCDIR)/drivers:$(SRCDIR)/doe:$(SRCDIR)/../gpl:$(SRCDIR)/../gpl/splines:$(SRCDIR)/../gpl/rbf

TARGET = m3explorer 

#####################################
#      CREATE RSM TARGETS           #
#####################################

RSM_TARGETS=

ifeq ("$(BUILDSHEPARD)", "yes")
RSM_TARGETS += sh_i 
CXXFLAGS += -D__M3_COMPILE_SHEPARD_RSM__
endif

ifeq ("$(BUILDSPLINE)", "yes")
RSM_TARGETS += spline 
CXXFLAGS += -D__M3_COMPILE_SPLINE_RSM__
endif

ifeq ("$(BUILDNEURAL)", "yes")
RSM_TARGETS += nn 
CXXFLAGS += -D__M3_COMPILE_NEURAL_RSM__
endif

ifeq ("$(BUILDRBF)", "yes")
RSM_TARGETS += rbf_interpolator
CXXFLAGS += -D__M3_COMPILE_RBF_RSM__
endif

ifeq ("$(BUILDREGRESSION)", "yes")
RSM_TARGETS += regressor
CXXFLAGS += -D__M3_COMPILE_REGRESSION_RSM__
endif

#####################################
#     CREATE BUILD TARGETS          #
#####################################

all: $(TARGET) $(OPTIMIZERS_TARGET) $(DRIVERS_TARGET) $(DOE_TARGET) $(RSM_TARGETS)

#############################
#       ENGINE BUILD        #
#############################

m3explorer: $(M3EXPLORER_TARGETS) 
    $(CXX) $(OTHERLINKFLAGS) $^ -o $@


%.o: %.cc $(M3EXPLORER_INCDIR_INCLUDES)
    $(CXX) -c  $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) 

%.so: %.cc $(M3EXPLORER_INCDIR_INCLUDES)
    $(CXX) $< -o $@ $(CXXSOFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) 

m3_grammar.o: $(SRCDIR)/m3_grammar.yy 
    cp $(SRCDIR)/m3_grammar.yy .
    bison -d $(SRCDIR)/m3_grammar.yy -o bof.cc
    cp bof*h* m3_grammar.h
    cp bof*cc m3_grammar.cc
    $(CXX) -c  m3_grammar.cc -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)

m3_tokens.o: $(SRCDIR)/m3_tokens.ll 
    flex $(SRCDIR)/m3_tokens.ll
    mv lex.yy.c m3_tokens.cc
    $(CXX) -c  m3_tokens.cc -o $@ -I. $(CXXFLAGS) 

#############################
#       RSM BUILD       #
#############################

XDR_DEPS= gpl_xdr_api.o gpl_xdr_api.h

gpl_xdr_api.o: gpl_xdr_api.cc gpl_xdr_api.h
    $(CXX) -c  $< -o $@ $(GPLCXXFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR)

sh_i: sh_i.cc $(XDR_DEPS) 
    $(CXX) -o gpl_xdr_api.o $@ $< $(GPLCXXFLAGS) $(GPLLINKFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR)

nn: cascade.c $(XDR_DEPS)
     $(CXX) -o gpl_xdr_api.o -lpthread $@ $< $(GPLCXXFLAGS) $(GPLLINKFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR)

SPLINE_OBJ=converter.o parameters.o spline.o r_wrapper.o spline_script.o
SPLINE_INC=r_wrapper.hpp spline_script.hpp converter.hpp parameters.h

$(SPLINE_OBJ): %.o: %.cc $(SPLINE_INC) 
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(GPLCXXFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR)

spline: $(SPLINE_OBJ) $(XDR_DEPS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(GPLCXXFLAGS) $(GPLLINKFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR) 

RBF_OBJ=bvp.o diff_op.o interpolator.o linalg.o utils.o ddm.o error.o func.o rbf.o interpolatorRBF.o
RBF_INC= bvp.hpp  ddm.hpp  diff_op.hpp  error.hpp  func.hpp  interpolator.hpp  linalg.hpp  rbf.hpp  utils.hpp

$(RBF_OBJ): %.o: %.cpp $(RBF_INC) 
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(GPLCXXFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR)

rbf_interpolator: $(RBF_OBJ) $(XDR_DEPS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(GPLCXXFLAGS) $(GPLLINKFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR) 

regressor: regressor.cc $(XDR_DEPS) 
    $(CXX) -o gpl_xdr_api.o $@ $< $(GPLCXXFLAGS) $(GPLLINKFLAGS) -I$(GPLDIR)

#############################
#       CLEAN BUILD     #
#############################

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET) *.cc *.hh *.so *.h *.yy
    rm -rf m3explorer* test*_output tmp

dist-clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET) *.cc *.hh *.so *.scr *.xml *.scr do_tests *.h *.yy doxygen.cfg makefile config.status
    rm -rf m3explorer* test*_output tmp $(RSM_TARGETS)

ifeq ("$(OS_NAME)", "Darwin")
dist:
            tar --directory $(SRCDIR)/../.. -c -v -z -f m3explorer_release_1_1_src.tar.gz m3explorer --exclude "*.svn*" --exclude "build"
endif

ifeq ("$(OS_NAME)", "Linux")
dist:
            tar --exclude="*.svn*" --directory $(SRCDIR)/../.. -c -v -z -f m3explorer_release_1_1_src.tar.gz m3explorer 
endif

doc:
            doxygen $(DSTDIR)/doxygen.cfg 

ifeq ("$(OS_NAME)", "Linux")
bin-dist: install doc
            tar --exclude="*.svn*" --directory $(IMAGE)/.. -c -v -z -f m3explorer_release_1_1_linux_$(shell uname -r)_bin.tar.gz $(shell cd $(IMAGE) && pwd | xargs basename) 
endif

ifeq ("$(OS_NAME)", "Linux")
doc-dist: install doc
            tar --exclude="*.svn*" --directory $(IMAGE) -c -v -z -f m3explorer_release_1_1_docs.tar.gz $(shell cd $(IMAGE)/doc && pwd | xargs basename) 
endif


#############################
#      INSTALL BUILD        #
#############################

# Note add: install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/*.ref $(IMAGE)/tests
# install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/stub_test.py $(IMAGE)/tests

install: all 
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/bin
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/lib
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/schemas
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/scripts
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/examples
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/examples/simple_sim
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/examples/beverage_can
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/examples/mpeg
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/rsm
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/tests
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/html
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/latex
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/html/template_results_page_files
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/*.so $(IMAGE)/lib
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/multicube_design_space_test*.xml $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/debug_*scr $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/create_*scr $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/do_tests $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../html/*.html $(IMAGE)/html
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../latex/*.tex $(IMAGE)/latex
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../html/template_results_page_files/* $(IMAGE)/html/template_results_page_files
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../schemas/*.xsd $(IMAGE)/schemas
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../scripts/*.scr $(IMAGE)/scripts
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../scripts/*.xml $(IMAGE)/examples/mpeg
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../scripts/full_*.gz $(IMAGE)/examples/mpeg
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../scripts/*mpeg* $(IMAGE)/examples/mpeg
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/test*output.ref $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/db7.xml.ref $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/test_xml*.scr $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/test_ff*.scr $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/mpeg_dse.scr $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/mpeg_export_xml.scr $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/pareto_mpeg4.db $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/stub_*.py $(IMAGE)/tests
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/simple_sim/simple_sim.py $(IMAGE)/examples/simple_sim
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/simple_sim/simple_sim_scr.scr $(IMAGE)/examples/simple_sim
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/simple_sim_ds.xml $(IMAGE)/examples/simple_sim
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/beverage_can/beverage_can.py $(IMAGE)/examples/beverage_can
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../tests/beverage_can/beverage_can_scr.scr $(IMAGE)/examples/beverage_can
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/beverage_can_ds.xml $(IMAGE)/examples/beverage_can
    install -m 744 $(SRCDIR)/../gpl/*xdr* $(IMAGE)/rsm
    @mkdir -p $(IMAGE)/include
    install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/m3explorer $(IMAGE)/bin
    @for hdr in $(INCDIR)/*.h ; do \
          if cmp -s $$hdr $(IMAGE)/include/`basename $$hdr`; then : ; else \
            echo "Installing $$hdr to $(IMAGE)/include"; \
            install -m 644 $$hdr $(IMAGE)/include; \
          fi; \
        done
    if [ -e $(DSTDIR)/sh_i ] ; then \
         install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/sh_i $(IMAGE)/rsm; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -e $(DSTDIR)/nn ] ; then \
         install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/nn $(IMAGE)/rsm; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -e $(DSTDIR)/spline ] ; then \
         install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/spline $(IMAGE)/rsm; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -e $(DSTDIR)/rbf_interpolator ] ; then \
         install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/rbf_interpolator $(IMAGE)/rsm; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -e $(DSTDIR)/regressor ] ; then \
         install -m 744 $(DSTDIR)/regressor $(IMAGE)/rsm; \
    fi ; \
    chmod a+x $(IMAGE)/bin/*
    chmod a+x $(IMAGE)/lib/*
    chmod a+x $(IMAGE)/rsm/*
    chmod a+x $(IMAGE)/tests/do_tests

install-doc: install doc
```

What can be the possible cause of error and how to solve it? I have checked with many earlier posts from blog. But couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List libraries *after* the object files, **not** before them.  Rewrite the build rule which is currently:

```
m3explorer: $(M3EXPLORER_TARGETS) 
    $(CXX) $(OTHERLINKFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

as:

```
m3explorer: $(M3EXPLORER_TARGETS) 
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(OTHERLINKFLAGS)
```

Personally, I'd include `$(CXXFLAGS)` in the link line too:

```
m3explorer: $(M3EXPLORER_TARGETS) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(OTHERLINKFLAGS)
```